# Is it possible to construct $20^\circ$ angle with the help of a compass?

Tags: geometry

Once my brother told me that construction of a $20^\circ$ angle with the help of a compass is impossible.

I searched for it on the net but I did not find anything about how to prove it.

Kindly prove or disprove the problem (and remember that I am asking for a $20^\circ angle$ exactly).

Comment: What your brother said is true. The proof is rather lengthy.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sir, at least provide the way to approach

Comment: For more information, please [see this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonagon comes very close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic angle in every construction using only ruler and compass is $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Every other angle can be constucted by bisecting this angle. Now note that $20^{\circ} = \frac{\pi}{9}$, i.e. three times the basic angle. It's been proven that angle trisection using ruler and compass is impossible, hence the proof.

You can read more about angle trisection [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection). Actually it's proven for $\frac{\pi}{9}$, that it's impossible to construct.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks for noticing my mistake and correcting it ;)

Comment: No problem. ${}{}{}$

Comment: So what about a [pentagon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Construction_of_a_regular_pentagon) and and angles of $\frac{\pi}{5}$?